# Trouble with Log in Debian 9

Tags: debian, login

I use a computer in a local network, and by that I mean that computers run Debian 9 and users' files are stored in a server not locally.

At the computer that I normally use, I accidentally gave wrong password more than two or three times and now when I give the correct one and continue to display the wrong password message.

I tried to log in from another computer of the network and logged in normally. How can I fix that?

**edit**. If the post needs more information, ask me and I will update/provide.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: The problem was that I could not log in with my user account. When I gave the correct password at log in it displayed wrong password message. I tried again after having passed a few hours, I logged in successfully. I believe it was a security thing because as I mention in my OP, I gave 2 or 3 times wrong password in log in .

Comment: It sounds like your connection to your remote server has a firewall, setup to frustrate remote attacks by only allowing a sensible number of password "mistakes". Search for a program such as **fail2ban**.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyBoden, I haven't thought that. I thought it was a Debian feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in a comment above, when I tried to log in after a few hours, I logged in successfully, so it must have been a security measure. As @Jerremy Boden mentioned also in a comment, it probably is a remote server configuration, but I didn't verify it.